# Trying to generate a patient ID for patients in laravel like (P001) laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to laravel and am trying to make a patient ID for my application that will auto increment in the patient registration form.

The auto increment works in the form input but when it reaches ten patients it's suppose to show "P0010" instead is showing "P00010". below id my code for the patient ID. I am using the id from the tag migration which I created. it works well for P001-P009 but from P0010 it keeps using only the first case statement. Thanks

```
public function getPatientTag($id)
{
    $tag = "P";

    switch(count($id)){
        case 1:
            $tag .= "000".$id;
            break;

        case 2:
            $tag .= "00".$id;
            break;

        case 3:
            $tag .= "0".$id;
            break;

    }

    return $tag;
}
```

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Certainly there is a string formatting function that can pad a number out to a specified number of zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_pad` for that. Try something like this:

```
public function getPatientTag($id)
{
    $tag = "P";
    return $tag . str_pad($id, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```